# Can I always use private set instead of private val in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I read some kotlin project samples code, I find many author like to Code A.

I think Code B is more simpler.

1: Is Code B good way?

2: Can I always use private set intead of private val in Android Studio?

**Code A**

```
private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(InterestsUiState(loading = true))
val uiState: StateFlow<InterestsUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()
```

**Code B**

```
var uiState = MutableStateFlow(InterestsUiState(loading = true))
    private set
```

Comment: I also wondered similar question when I was learning `ViewModel` and `LiveData`.

Comment: Answering your second question: yes, if you need `var` inside the class and `val` outside then `private set` is the way to go. But this is not the case here. Code A uses `val` for both inside and outside, but changes from `MutableStateFlow` to `StateFlow`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A, B are not the same code.

In code A, define another variable as `StateFlow` is preventing to change value in `StateFlow` from out of class.

In code B, you can update value in `StateFlow` from out of class.
Because you can refer `MutableStateFlow`.

Mutating state variable itself and Mutating state in `StateFlow` is different.

Observer observing `StateFlow` is received event when value in `StateFlow` is change but change `StateFlow` itself.

In other word, you should use code A for prevent to unexpected mutating from outer

Comment: Thanks! But I have set `var uiState` as  `private set` in Code B, I think I can only update  `var uiState` inside class, just like Code A, right?

Comment: @HelloCW No. `private set` make `var` look like a `val` externally, but it is still `MutableStateFlow`, so you can still modify its contents (as its name suggests). You need to understand the difference between `val`/`var` and `StateFlow`/`MutableStateFlow`. They are two independent kinds of mutability/immutability that work together. You can have `val MutableStateFlow` and `var StateFlow` and they are much different things. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51718229/kotlin-val-mutablelist-vs-var-immutablelist-when-to-use-which Especially second answer, listing all 4 possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this example

```
var userName by mutableStateOf("")
   private set
```

but what i thought is best for a better encapsulation is this ,to deny the possibility of mutating the useName from outside the single source of truth (the viewmodel holder and responsible for managing the state )

```
  private var _userName by mutableStateOf("")
    val userName
        get() = _userName
```