# Why declare mutableLiveData class with val type?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata, android-livedata-transformations

Why not use mutableLiveData of the val type as a substitute for the var type?

Isn't it a violation to be able to set on the val type?

---

Like, for example:

1. Example of a val type

```
class LoadDetailViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _liveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val liveData: LiveData<String> get() = _liveData

    fun loadData() = viewModelScope.launch {
        _liveData.value = "value"
        _liveData.postValue("value")
    }
}
```

---

2. Code changed to var type

```
class LoadDetailViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private var _liveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
    var liveData: LiveData<String> get() = _liveData

    fun loadData() = viewModelScope.launch {
        _liveData.value = "value"
        _liveData.postValue("value")
    }
}
```

---

But the result is still equivalent.
There is no error when I declare mutableLiveData as var, but I don't know why I have to declare it as val.

---

- I understand that the val type in the Kotlin language is an immutable type, and the var type is a mutable type.
- Then isn't it right to declare it as a var type?

---

[Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MutableLiveData)
I looked up the official documents of Android, but there was no answer to them.

Comment: Very closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51718229/5133585

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `_liveData.value = "value"`, notice you are not using `_liveData =`. So you are not mutating the property `_liveData` and it doesn't need to be a `var`. You are mutating the property *inside* the MutableLiveData.

It is wrong to use `var` for this, because you are not swapping out the instance of `MutableLiveData`. If you changed it to a different instance, your observers would not be notified.

You are confusing mutability of the property (the thing that holds a reference to an instance of MutableLiveData) with the class (the MutableLiveData itself). MutableLiveData is a mutable class because it has mutable variables inside it. You can mutate it, but you don't want to mutate the property that is holding a reference to it.

Using `var` isn't causing any problems because you haven't actually utilized the mutability to change the reference to a different instance. But since you should never want to do that, there is no reason to use `var` instead of `val`. It makes code clearer and more robust to use `val`.